# Como mostrar un informe con jasperreport al dar click en un boton?

Tags: java, jquery, jsp, spring, jasper-reports

Tengo el siguiente código en mi jsp, y lo que quiero hacer es que al dar click en el botón me mande a otra pagina para mostrar el reporte, lo que hace es que si entra a mi método que tengo en el controlador pero no muestra nada ni marca error

```html
<script>
 function generarDocumento(){
  var data = "consultaForm";
  var url: "${pageContext.request.ContextPath}/report";
  $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: url,
  contentType: "application/json",
  data: data,
  dataType: 'json',
  
  });
 
 }
</script>
<form id="consultaForm">

 <button type="button" onclick="generarDocumento();">GENERAR</button>

</form>
```

y el código en mi controlador

```html
@RequestMapping("/report")
public String verReporte(Model model, @RequestParam(name = "format", defaultValue="pdf", required = false) String format{

 model.addAttribute("format", format);
 model.addAttribute("datasource", facturaService.consultaAll());
 model.addAttribute("autor", "Dev");

 return "prueba_reporte";
 
 
}
```

y es que si entro a la url `/report` directamente en el navegador si me muestra mi reporte, pero yo quiero hacerlo desde mi boton de mi jsp
como le puedo hacer?

Que tengo que cambiar para mandarlo desde mi botón?
Gracias-

Comment: Con el ajax solo no podrás redireccionar, mi pregunta es si la ruta que colocas en el ajax es la ruta que al final te muestra el reporte o el ajax deberia de obtener algun valor de esa url para luego redireccionar?

Comment: Pues en el ajax puse la ruta que tengo en mi método del.controlador, que es la que muestra el reporte, pero no muestra nada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

De verdad es necesario usar ajax para cargar tu reporte? Porque veo que el data que mandas en ajax solo es un string.
Entonces por qué no hacerlo por GET con un simple enlace?

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.ContextPath}/report">Generar</a>
```

O bien si usas Bootstrap puedes darle estilo de botón al enlace:

```
<a href="${pageContext.request.ContextPath}/report" class="btn btn-default">Generar</a>
```

Si es necesario mandar los datos por POST puedes hacerlo de esta manera

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.ContextPath}/report" method="POST" target="_blank">
  <input type="hidden" name="param1" value="value1">
  <input type="hidden" name="param2" value="value2">
  <input type="submit" value="GENERAR"></form>
```

De esta manera los datos se mandarán por POST y el resultado se abrirá en una nueva ventana o pestaña.

Answer (score 1):

Si siempre vas a enviar los datos por POST al reporte deberías cambiar

```
@RequestMapping("/report")
```

por

```
@RequestMapping(value={"/report"}, method=RequestMethod.POST)
```